# C# ConcurrentDictonary Setting values in collection other then the key

Tags: c#-4.0

Please look through my code before closing it this time.

The code below works but seems very hacked, I am looking for suggestions on to achieve the same thing with cleaner code or is this as good as it gets.

The code calling the Add and Remove will be from different threads that could possible access the code at the same time, so it must remain thread-safe.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

namespace Server
{
    public class Company
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public ConcurrentDictionary<string, Employee> Employees = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Employee>();
    }

    public class Employee
    {
        public string First { get; set; }
        public string Last { get; set; }
        public string Ext { get; set; }
    }

    public class Clients
    {
        public ConcurrentDictionary<string, Company> CompaniesDict = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Company>();


        public bool Add_Company(string ID, string Name, string Address, string Phone) //This function works
        {

            Company MyCompany = new Company();
            Employee MyEmployees = new Employee();

            MyCompany.Name = Name;
            MyCompany.Address = Address;
            MyCompany.Phone = Phone;
            MyCompany.Employees = MyEmployees;

            return CompaniesDict.TryAdd(ID, MyCompany);

        }

        public bool Remove_Company(string ID) //This function works
        {

            return CompaniesDict.TryRemove(ID, Company tCompany);

        }

        //This is were I need the help this seems so hacked. Im not trying to update the key, but the value intstead
        public bool Set_CompanyName(string ID, string Name) 
        {

            CompaniesDict.TryGetValue(ID, out Company oCompany);

            Company nCompany;
            nCompany = oCompany;
            nCompany.Name = Name;

            return CompaniesDict.TryUpdate(ID, nCompany, oCompany);
        }

        public string Get_CompanyName(string ID)
        {

            CompaniesDict.TryGetValue(ID, out Company tCompany);

            return tCompany.Name;
        }


    }
}
```

Please don't just close this and link me to some useless code you call a duplicate. Sorry to be so blunt but this has recently happened to me by a fellow coder on this site. If you have questions that I can answer so that you can full help me please ask them.

Thanks for you help in advance.

Comment: You should not construct objects that are going to be overwritten as 'out' parameters.

Comment: I believe I have corrected that in the code above, I am still very new to C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a much easier approach, as you are updating a field on an object.
Please note that I don't have C# installed on my current PC, so can't validate this.

Note that I declare the out parameter, but don't construct a new one that would be destroyed immediately and I modify the object itself. 
i.e.

```
Company company;
```

not

Company company=new Company();

This will still not be deterministic if multiple threads call SetCompanyName(), as the new name is updated on the live object and there could be a potential race condition. However the Add and Remove will be, even if Remove removes the company instance just before its name is updated.

```
public bool Set_CompanyName(string ID, string Name) 
{
   Company company; 
   var retval= CompaniesDict.TryGetValue(ID, out company)
   if (retval) {
       company.Name=Name; // Update your company object directly
    }
//else Do something such as throw an exception if it's not found
    return retval;
 }
```